# Send custom value/data to PayPal (Express Checkout)

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am following this tutorial [PHP Shopping Cart to PayPal (Express Checkout)](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/07/php-multiple-items-shopping-cart-integration-with-paypal). Can anyone tell me how can I send any custom/additional data/value to paypal e.g. I want to send an **Order Number** and a **Customer ID** that belongs to a particular order among these 4 variables as below:

```
$paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'.$key.'='. urlencode($_POST['item_qty'][$key]);
$paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'.$key.'='.urlencode($_POST['item_price'][$key]);
$paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'.$key.'='.urlencode($_POST['item_name'][$key]);
$paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER'.$key.'='.urlencode($_POST['item_code'][$key]);
```

Comment: did you mention to send a custom value/data pair and get it back from PayPal?? Would you like to share?

Comment: FYI: found new variables to use here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the API reference for [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/).  It'll show you all the parameters available to send in that final call that processes everything with PayPal.

You'll notice there's an INVOICE parameter you can send your order number in, and that invoice number would be returned in IPN notifications, PayPal transaction details, etc.  Then you should be able to pull the related customer ID from your own database once you retrieve that invoice ID.

If you do want to go ahead and send it, though, or any other info you can use the CUSTOM parameter and send up to 256 characters.  If you have multiple fields you want to send there you could do|it|like|this and then parse the values back out when you retrieve that field later.

On a side note, I'd recommend taking a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It'll make stuff like this a lot easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM

field.